# Fatal error when scroll down

Tags: ios, json, swift

i am passing json in tableView, but it show the message "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when i am scrolling down a few times

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

    var imageUrlString: String?

    func loadImageUsingUrlString(_ urlString: String) {

        imageUrlString = urlString

         let urlEncoded = urlString.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

        let url = URL(string: urlEncoded!)

        image = nil

        if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.image = imageFromCache
            return
        }


        // crush here down line
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(myData, respones, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? 0)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                let imageToCache = UIImage(data: myData!)

                if self.imageUrlString == urlString {
                    self.image = imageToCache
                }

                imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
            })

        }).resume()
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: the only force unwrap I see is url! so url might be nil. So before calling data task check if url is nil or not thats all and if you are wondering why url is nil obviously string urlEncoded u passed to URL init wasn't a proper url

Comment: It must be your `url` unwrap your `url`.

Comment: put your code no screen shot

Comment: @MikeAlter i posted code

Comment: Try to use [SDWebImage]https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage. `imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlStr), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` in a `if-let` clause like this:

```
if let url = url {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(myData, respones, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error ?? 0)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            let imageToCache = UIImage(data: myData!)

            if self.imageUrlString == urlString {
                self.image = imageToCache
            }

            imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
        })

    }).resume()
}
```

**Note:** And also try not to use `force-unwrapping` (`!`) as long as possible. Instead use `optional binding` with `if-let` everywhere possible.

---

### Edit

As you might be new with `optional`s I'm posting the possible crash handled code. Though I didn't change the logics, I fixed possible crash related code:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

    var imageUrlString: String?

    func loadImageUsingUrlString(_ urlString: String) {

        imageUrlString = urlString

        guard let urlEncoded = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {
            print("Encoding not done")
            return
        }

        let url = URL(string: urlEncoded)

        image = nil

        if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.image = imageFromCache
            return
        }


        if let url = url {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(myData, respones, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error ?? 0)
                    return
                }

                if let myData = myData {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                        let imageToCache = UIImage(data: myData)

                        if self.imageUrlString == urlString {
                            self.image = imageToCache
                        }

                        if let imageToCache = imageToCache {
                            imageCache.setObject(imageToCache, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                        }
                    })
                }

            }).resume()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: after add your code. got the thread another line.  this is    imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)

Comment: @AzmalTech I suggested you to put `if-let` binding everywhere else where you are putting `!` operator. But you didn't.

Comment: can you help to answer this question. i want to detect one button in tableview cell on click. here is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970198/how-to-detect-one-button-in-tableview-cell?noredirect=1#comment84948065_48970198

Answer (score 0):

You need to check url before use

For that you can use this two options

1) `if let`

2) `guard let` (Better)

i.e

Here Replace this code

```
    let url = URL(string: urlEncoded!)
```

with

```
 guard let  url = URL(string: urlEncoded) else {
    print("Your Url is nil")
     return
 }
```

> > Before you forcefully unwarp you must sure about value otherwise put it in if let or guard let block

And also use `guard let` at  here too

```
    guard  let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage else {
     return
    }
```

It makes your code easy to read

Hope it helps to you

Comment: @AzmalTech what is imagePreview ?

Comment: image data is not load

Comment: @AzmalTech From Cache ? , Then you need to  put statement   ` guard  let imageFromCache` as first line then create url

Answer (score 0):

**might be url is nil so try this code.**

```
if url.absoluteString != "" {

 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(myData, respones, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error ?? 0)
                    return
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    let imageToCache = UIImage(data: myData!)

                    if self.imageUrlString == urlString {
                        self.image = imageToCache
                    }

                    imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                })

            }).resume()
        }
```

Comment: thread goes to this line after use your code          imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)